# nerdy question about Conditional (ternary) without false statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, ecmascript-6

My question very simple and read [this document](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-conditional-operator) for get my answer but I didn't find it and of course google it and nothing found.

Question is, if I use Conditional Operator ( ? : ) without false statement like below example is harmful for heap or memory or ... in Node.js?

```js
    let val="hello";
    "hi"=="hi" ? val="hi" :0;
    console.log(val);
    val="";
    "hi"!="hi" ? val="hi" :0;
    console.log(val);
```

As you see code is work fine but what happen for 0 (False statement), is this harmful?

Comment: What is the concern? Harmful how? If you mean: Does the false expression get evaluated -> No, it get's short circuited just like `false && <not-evaluated>` or `true || <not-evaluated>`

Comment: i don't understand why you say there's no false statement. there is. 
`true ? val="hi" : 0;` returns `hi` and `false ? val="hi" : 0` returns 0.

Comment: @junvar and keithpjolley,  Thanks for your response what happens for 0  if condition is return false ?  Zero(0) must be store some where in heap or memory or not store ? is it harmful use that form?

Comment: @H.T since you don't have identifier for the `0` so it will be garbage collected, so there's no memory related issues, if you think about issue yes there is readability and misuse of ternary operator, why not just write simple branching statement, leave this saving of line of minifying tools.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you have reinvented the if statement!

You code is just a more complicated version of:

```
if (condition) val = "hi";
```

In javascript, the interpreter will ignore the result of expressions that aren't assigned to anything, so if `condition` is false, you end up with the statement `0;`, which is a noop. It's a lot more readable to just use an if statement.

Comment: Dude Are you kidding me ? I know what happen in true statement! I need to know what happen if `condition` is false and `false statement` is value `0` . this value will store in heap or memory or some-where or compiler ignore it ?

Comment: My answer already says the interpreter ignores it. You shouldn't even have to worry about this because if you're not using the `else` clause, you should just use an `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response but what happen if condition call `else` clause? (`else` clause impotent for me. when compiler read 0, what is next step of processing for ES6 in **node.js** compiler?) I use this from of syntax in a project and this form of syntax work fine but i need to sure in `else` clause value will be garbage or don't reserve any memory or ... . Do you see any documentation about this situation ?